# How do I work with complex numbers in CUSPARSE?

Tags: cuda

I'm currently working with CUSPARSE. I'm having trouble because I don't know how to print a complex number. For example, when I write:

cuComplex a;

a.x=1.2;

a.y=2.2;

How do I print the varable a?
I've tried :

cout<< a;

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to overload the `<<` operator to take in cuComplex and cuDoubleComplex data types.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const cuComplex& in)
{
    char sgn[2] = "+-"
    strm << in.x << sgn[in.y < 0] << " i"<< std::abs(in.y);
    return strm;
}
```

You can do the same for cuDoubleComplex

Comment: You can do that, but frankly I wouldn't let those plain low-level unabstracted types anywhere near an `ostream::operator<<`.

Answer (score 1):

The data in `std::complex` is identical to the corresponding data in a cuComplex, i.e. you can `reinterpret_cast` pointers (and therefore arrays, too) of one type to the other – it works in practise and is, I think, actually guaranteed by C++11, you can test it like this:

```
namespace check_stdComplexdouble_to_cuDoubleComplex_binary_compatibility{
  using std::complex;

  const complex<double> testarr[] = { complex<double>(0.,.5)
                                    , complex<double>(1.,1.5) };
  const cuDoubleComplex* cucomplexd
     = reinterpret_cast<const cuDoubleComplex*>(testarr);
  auto tester() -> bool {
    assert( cuCreal(cucomplexd[0])==0. && cuCimag(cucomplexd[0])==.5
                && cuCreal(cucomplexd[1])==1. && cuCimag(cucomplexd[1])==1.5 );
    return true;
  }
  const bool ok = tester();
  bool good(){return ok;}
};
```

If you call a CUBLAS function that's supposed to read/write from/to an `std::complex<float>`, you can just give it a `reinterpret_cast`ed pointer, e.g.

```
  std::complex<double> result;
  xhandle->cublasstat = yhandle->cublasstat
     = cublasZdotc( *xhandle->cublashandle
                  , xhandle->vect_dimension
                  , xhandle->vector, 1
                  , yhandle->vector, 1
                  , reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&result) );
```